# jqgrid not showing XML data whit special characters (ñ and accents)

Tags: xml, jqgrid, character-encoding

I just deployed a php application that uses jqgrid, the problem is that the jqgrid loads data from XML responses, on Google Chrome it works, ugly but it works, some weird characters are replacing the accent characters and the ñ.

On IE and firefox, not working at all.

What are the things I must check?

All in the application is using utf-8 but the database (sql server) has COLLATE = Modern_Spanish_CI_AS

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't important in with which collate you save data in the database. It's important just that the server provide Ajax response from the server will be encoded in UTF-8 (charset=UTF-8). If you do so you should have no problems. Additionally you should include `charset` or `http-equiv="content-type"` `<meta>` in the `<head>` of your page which have jqGrid. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file) for the code example.

Answer (score 0):

What might also matter is the encoding set in your HTTP header. There is a bunch of other stuff, too. Check this thread out - http://codemerx.com/jqgrid/forum/jqgrid-standalone/2-special-characters-in-jqgrid

Comment: Can you add more detail about the OP should be paying attention to?  It's better if the meat of the answer is in the post itself, rather than on a linked page which may not persist.